# What is $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Supposing that the set is $A=\{a,b,c\}$. The set of parts of $A$ is the set that has as its elements all possible subsets of the set $A$. By all possible subsets of $A$ we mean precisely all its subsets, including improper ones, that is, the empty set and the set $A$ itself.

We have $$\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \} = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\}$$$$ = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A\}$$

I must to find $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. If I indicate the elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ with $S_1, S_2, \ldots S_8$, I can build

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))= \{S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5, S_6, S_7, S_8, \{S_1, S_2\},\{S_1, S_3\},\\\{S_1, S_4\},\ldots\{S_1, S_8\}, \{S_2, S_3\}\ldots,\{S_2, S_8\},\ldots\}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))= \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, A, \{\emptyset, \{a\}\},\\\{\{a\}, \{b\}\},\{\{b\}, \{c\}\},\ldots\{\emptyset, A\}, \{\{a\}, \{b\}\}\ldots,\{\{a\}, A\},\ldots\}$$

and so on. Is it correct? If $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^n$ elements how many elements does it have $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$?

> If the definition of $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ B \mid B \subseteq A \}$ what is the definition of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$?

Comment: Well...if $S$ is a finite set with $k$ elements then $\mathcal P(S)$ has $2^k$ elements, so...

Comment: $S_2,\dots,S_8$ are elements of $\mathcal P(A),$ not of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A)).$

Comment: @lulu This fact is written in my question. $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^n$.

Comment: Ok...and so $\mathcal P(A)$ is a finite set with $2^n$ elements.  It follows that $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A))$ has...

Comment: @AnneBauval Maybe I should write $S_1$ to $S_8$ all with curly brackets?

Comment: @RobArthan Why? $A=\{a, b, c\}\subseteq A$?

Comment: Please avoid having subject lines that have nothing but MathJax code in them; they break some navigation shortcuts.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I hope ti have understood. Thank you vey much.

Comment: Why there is a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not correct:

$\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))=\lbrace\emptyset,  \lbrace\emptyset\rbrace , \lbrace \lbrace a\rbrace \rbrace , \lbrace \lbrace b \rbrace \rbrace, \lbrace \lbrace c\rbrace \rbrace,\lbrace \lbrace a \rbrace, \emptyset \rbrace, \ldots\rbrace$

and $|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))|=2^{|\mathcal{P}(A)|}=2^{2^n}$

Comment: I thank you. Could you please build them all for me? Why there is the only $\emptyset$ without curly brackets?

Comment: I think my examples show the pattern. As the lower calculation indicates, I would need to write down 256 elements :)

Comment: The empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: No no :-)  But I would like to understand the construction mechanism.

Comment: To list the elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ where $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$, list all the singleton subsets, then list all the two-element subsets by considering all possible ways of adding one of the $x_i$ to a two-element subset striking out duplicates, now carry on to list all the three-element subsets in the same way using the list of two-element subsets and so on.

Comment: Basically you need to add curly brackets around all the sets in your question. And add $\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(A)$

Comment: @CoffeeArabica It is true. $\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(A) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal P(A))$.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica I have not understood the downvote.

Comment: I did not downvote :0

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the 256 elements of $P(P(A))$:
{φ, {φ}, {{a}}, {{b}}, {{c}}, {{a, b}}, {{a, c}}, {{b, c}}, {φ, {a}}, {φ, {b}}, {φ, {c}}, {{b}, {a}}, {{c}, {a}}, {{c}, {b}}, {{a, b, c}}, {φ, {a, b}}, {φ, {a, c}}, {φ, {b, c}}, {{a}, {a, b}}, {{a}, {a, c}}, {{b, c}, {a}}, {{b}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {a, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}}, {{c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a}}, {φ, {c}, {a}}, {φ, {c}, {b}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}}, {φ, {a, b, c}}, {{a, c}, {a, b}}, {{a}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b}}, {{b, c}, {a, c}}, {{b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}}, {φ, {b}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {a, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}}, {{a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a, b, c}}, {{a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}}, {φ, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}}, {{a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {φ, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {φ, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {{c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, {φ, {c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}}

Comment: Impressive. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

A useful way to think about this is to use the correspondence between a subset $S$ of $A$ and its characteristic functions $1_S$, where $1_S\colon A \to \{0,1\}$ is given by
$$
1_S(a) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1, & \text{ if } a \in S \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Clearly the correspondence $S\leftrightarrow 1_S$ gives a bijection between $\mathcal P(A)$ and the set of all function $\{f\colon A\to \{0,1\}\}$. If we write, for any two sets $X$ and $Y$, $Y^X= \{f\mid f\colon X\to Y\}$ for the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ (sometimes also denote $\text{Map}(X,Y)$), and denote $\{0,1\}$ by "$\mathbf 2$", then our bijection $S\leftrightarrow 1_S$ is a natural bijection between $\mathcal P(A)$ and $\mathbf 2^A$.

This notation is consistent with the standard exponent notation, because $|\mathbf 2^A| = 2^{|A|}$. It also makes it easy to see that
$$
\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A)) = \mathbf 2^{\mathbf 2^A}
$$
and hence
$|\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A))| = 2^{|\mathbf 2^{A}|} = 2^{2^{|A|}}$.

The notation $X^Y$ is quite well-behaved: for example, if $X,Y$ and $Z$ are sets then there is a natural bijection $(Z^{Y})^X \cong Z^{Y\times X}$ between $\text{Map}(X,\text{Map}(Y,Z)$ and $\text{Map}(X\times Y, Z)$: if $\theta\colon \text{Map}(X,Y) \to Z$, then given $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ if we set $\tilde{\theta}(x,y) = \theta(x)(y)$, it is easy to see that the correspondence $\theta\to \tilde{\theta}$ is bijective, and so we can lift the numerical identity $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ to the level of functions.

Comment: Thank you very much +1